# How to add an on click event in server side for an Image control in C#/ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, controls

I have added an image from toolbox in VS2008, and noticed that there isn't an onclick event in server side.

How do I add one on?

Answer (score 9):

***Image control*** is just to display an image on the Web page. There is no onlick event in Image control.

**asp:ImageButton Control**  that handles mouse clicks on images .

Answer (score 0):

Use the ImageButton control:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.aspx